# When to push and when to build?

Tags: company-of-heroes

At the beginning of the game I've decided it's important to spread out thinly, avoid enemy contact, and claim as many resource points as possible.  Yes?

But then it's less clear to me when is the best time to engage the enemy?

If I counter attack as soon as they start taking my resources I seem to get drawn into endless unit production and make inadequate progress on infrastructure;

But if I leave them to it, and I build, then I find myself unable to replenish my resources quickly enough to build those superior units.

Any tips on how to balance these two extremes? What events might signal to me that it's time to swap my focus?

Comment: Do you have any expansions (Tales of Valor and Opposing Fronts) installed? What faction do you prefer?

Comment: Yes. For arguments sake, let's say 'Allies'.

Answer (score 3):

There are proven opening sequences for every faction/map. There are numerous videos on YouTube which I used as tutorials. It also varies if you are playing against computer or a real person.

Usually what I as American is try to claim half of the map and situationally harass deeper into his territory. For Brits I take 2/5 of the map and build some defenses and then advance.